# Запись данных в три таблицы базы данных через один запрос (массив)

Tags: mysqli, php7, laravel-5.6

Как организовать запись данных через request имея три таблицы базы данных,.
Запрос имеет 12 полей от клиента, в каждой таблице есть по 4 поля, возможно ли передать  на запись все полученные данные в разные таблицы нужным полям с одного запроса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только если запрос выполняет вызов хранимой процедуры (CALL), которая раскладывает переданные ей данные по таблицам. Запрос INSERT может вставлять записи только в одну таблицу.

Ну и всякая экзотическая хрень, типа вставки в одну таблицу и передачи всех параметров в некоей сериализованной форме (причём в таблице должно быть поле, которое такое значение формально может принять), где BEFORE INSERT триггер ловит этот параметр, парсит, и раскладывает в две другие таблицы.

Примеры реализации:

```sql
-- структура тестовых таблиц
create table test1 (id int not null primary key, txt text)
create table test2 (id int not null primary key, txt text)
```

```sql
create procedure pr (in id int, in test1txt text, in test2txt text)
begin
insert into test1 
    select id, test1txt where test1txt is not null;
insert into test2 
    select id, test2txt where test2txt is not null;
end;
```

```sql
create trigger tr 
before insert 
on test1
for each row
begin
    insert into test2 
        select new.id, substring_index(new.txt, ',', -1)
        where locate(',', new.txt);
    set new.txt = substring_index(new.txt, ',', 1);
end;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=78c2aac456d9817bfd5a78cdc00db984)*